# use Dynamic with inheritance to allow user to create any method signature with a fixed name?

Tags: c#, dynamic

I have a base class that implements most of the stuff I need. I want an API user to write an inherited class with function that could have any signature, yet a fixed name.

Something that conceptually would work like

`(ValueTuple out) Act(ValueTuple in)`

for an unlimited amount of user-selected arguments so that one API user could write something like:

`(bool, Message) Act(List<Packet> ps)`

and another one could write something like:

`List<OtherMessage> Act(Packages ps, Status s)`

I would like them to write only one such function per class inheriter. Currently, I use annotation [Act] to get which function was declared by the user, yet it is not clear for users that she/he needs to write it looking at the base class.

Can we make it inherit some Dynamic(Expando)Object or have a dynamic field in order to achieve such behaviour, meaning have a base class like (pseudocode):

```
class Base : DynamicObject {
    public virtual dynamic Act;
}
```

which users could overload with something like (pseudocode):

```
class Client : Base {
    public new List<OtherMessage> Act(Packages ps, Status s){ return null; }
}
```

Comment: If you want full flexibility then you can simply pass and return an Object.  Also, can't you use an Interface?

Comment: So basically you want your users to implement a method with a known name, but unknown parameters list and unknown return types, is that correct?

Comment: Are you trying to achieve true polymorphism? Meaning, do you intend to do something such as: `Base x = new Client(); var y = x.Act(...);`? Such a thing would not make much sense if you ask me

Comment: @ZoharPeled: yes indeed. I get all parameters info via reflection at runtime due to other application needs

Comment: @YotamSalmon: yes, yet I do it via [Dynamitey Curry](https://github.com/ekonbenefits/dynamitey/wiki/UsageCurry) for calls and reflection with business logic for arguments list checking and gathering.

Comment: I want a nice API, having something like `object[] Act(object[])` in the base class is not at all what I desire.

Comment: Perhaps using generics? `IBase<TIn, TOut> { TOut Act(TIn paramerter); }`

Comment: I need unlimited args in and out amount..